# Copying current index into new index to use updated mapping/index template (ElasticSearch)

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I've recently been stuck in some issues where I had the incorrect mapping for a given index, so I had to create proper index template (or simply a mapping in some cases) although I'm aware the mappings only take affect on new indexes at that point.  I would like to know how to copy over the data of an existing index to a new index.  I've read a few things mentioning scan and scroll although I can't seem to find any concrete examples of how to do this.

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have created an application that can help you to do just this. If you do not like the application you can have a look at the code as well and just copy what you need:

https://github.com/jettro/maintain-elastic

Have a look at the following two classes to see what to do:
[https://github.com/jettro/maintain-elastic/.../IndexCreator.java](https://github.com/jettro/maintain-elastic/blob/master/elastic/src/main/java/nl/gridshore/dwes/index/IndexCreator.java)
[https://github.com/jettro/maintain-elastic/.../ScrollAndBulkIndexContentCopier.java](https://github.com/jettro/maintain-elastic/blob/master/elastic/src/main/java/nl/gridshore/dwes/index/ScrollAndBulkIndexContentCopier.java)